# i cant identify the model number of my nvidia card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have recently bought lenovo z50-70 laptop but i am not sure the model of my nvidia card because Ubuntu cant see it even when  scan for drivers from ***additional drivers*** it shows that there are no drivers in use . I tried to download hardinfo from the store but it also cant see it , so what is the steps I should take to identify its model.please note that I cant download any drivers online since I don’t know the exact model of this card.any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Please go to your BIOS and look whether the card has been activated...

Comment: So? what's the feed-back?  **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

Please try running the following command in terminal:

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

It should return information about your graphics details.

Comment: it doesn't show my dedicated card it only shows my integrated VGA Intel card  , is there is any method to make the OS  detect it  ???